# "Back" button in bottom of the screen in Navigation-based app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uinavigationbar

I'm developing nav-based app and I want to make "back" button and all navigation bar in bottom of the screen. It's possible? Help me please. Thx.

Comment: bottom - like tabbar, or maybe better use toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available using the standard UINavigationController. From the documentation, they says that you must never change the nav bar's frame or bounds.

If you need this feature you will have to:

1. hide the original navigationBar
2. create you own toolbar at the bottom as a subview of the main windows and always on top.
3. mimic the animations by listening to UINavigationControllerDelegate methods

Should be workable, but a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Thx, probably better to use toolbar's